# Where does JRuby look for scripts?

Tags: ruby, jruby, rubygems

Running the command `jruby -S spec` gives the following error

```
No such file, directory, or command -- spec
```

The location of spec is `/usr/bin`, which is in the path. Rspec is installed. MRI Ruby can find the script. JRuby can find the rspec gem. So what goes wrong?

Comment: This question hasn't got a correct answer yet, and I'm still interested in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of JRuby, when using the `-S` option, JRuby looks for the file in 3 different locations:

1. In the current directory,
2. In $JRUBY_HOME/bin
3. On the PATH (not LOAD_PATH)

This can be verified by adding a script (here called `test_it` that merely prints `hello`) in `/tmp`:

```
sebastien@greystones:~$ jruby -v 
jruby 1.6.6.dev (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-01-22 9099561) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_30) [linux-amd64-java]
sebastien@greystones:~$ jruby -S test_it
jruby: No such file or directory -- test_it (LoadError)
sebastien@greystones:~$ export PATH=/tmp:$PATH
sebastien@greystones:~$ jruby -J-Djruby.debug.scriptResolution=true -S test_it
Found: /tmp/test_it
hello
```

Here the `debug.scriptResolution` option is used to tell us where the script has been found.

Comment: Just adding this answer to provide an up-to-date answer to this issue, as I came across a similar problem recently.  Not sure whether the original issue was caused by using an older version of JRuby?

Answer (score 2):

JRuby will try to load scripts from directories on the classpath.  You can see what these are by running:

```
jruby -e "puts $:"
```

On the command line you can modify the $LOAD_PATH with the -I option.  Or add a library with the -r option.  For example:

```
jruby -I/usr/bin spec
```

Here is some more info on loadpath and classpath:

http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/ClasspathAndLoadPath

Hope that helps

Comment: That doesn't work, /usr/bin is not in the load path, nor should it be. - I'm using the -S option which is supposed to look at the PATH environment variable - but it doesn't.

Comment: Apparently, `jruby -S` only looks in `$JRUBY_HOME/bin`, not in the PATH, although the docs say it does look in PATH.

Comment: `cp /usr/bin/spec ~/git/jruby/bin` and it works, but this is really a band-aid solution.